Verify sequence is increasing
I have a dataset of approx 10,000 records. It contains approx 3,000 unique IDs and each ID has 2+ rows with associated variables.
What I need to check is whether the expected 1 year age progression makes sense relative to the dates of one of the other variables. (I have no date_of_birth).
e.g.
CORRECT



ID
sample_date
age




123456
04/07/2023
47


123456
15/11/2023
47


123456
08/02/2024
48



INCORRECT



ID
sample_date
age




123456
04/07/2023
47


123456
15/11/2023
47


123456
08/02/2024
46



I have sourced code (from stack overflow text) that identifies age mismatches relative to the ID number, this code works great.
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

#get the gender of the final observation for each ID
df[df[,Sex[.N],by=ID], recent_Sex:=(i.V1), on="ID"]

#find if there are any mismatches by ID
df[,mismatch:=any(recent_Sex!=Sex), by=ID]

Age differences greater than 1 year are low in number and easy for me to sight check. However, age differences of 1 year only are approx 3,000 records and I'm looking for a quick way to check that these are ok without having to go through each row!

The question to which you have a link is tagged R. Your question has neither R, nor Pandas, nor a database as a tag. What technology are you using / seeking a solution?

I would recommend using the lubridate package.
With your data, you can only know someone's age within 364 days, so if you compare days elapsed and 365 * age (I realize I'm ignoring leap years), then this will be very close.
The dplyr package may also help you:
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID=c(123456),
                 sample_date=c('04/07/2023', '15/11/2023', '08/02/2024'),
                 age=c(47,47,46))
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%

  mutate(sample_date = lubridate::dmy(sample_date),
         span = sample_date - first(sample_date),
         days_aged = 365*age - 365*first(age)) %>%
  summarize(discrepancy = any(span - days_aged > 365))

# A tibble: 1 × 2
      ID discrepancy
   <dbl> <lgl>
1 123456 TRUE

This assumes the dates are sorted, you may need to sort them yourself using arrange.

Assuming your sample_date is already in an ascending manner, then maybe you can try this
setDT(df)
df[
    ,
    match := var(as.integer(format(as.IDate(sample_date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y")) - age) == 0, 
    ID
][]

which gives
       ID sample_date   age    match
    <int>      <char> <int>   <lgcl>
1: 123456  04/07/2023    47     TRUE
2: 123456  15/11/2023    47     TRUE
3: 123456  08/02/2024    48     TRUE

data
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(123456L, 123456L, 123456L), sample_date = c("04/07/2023",
"15/11/2023", "08/02/2024"), age = c(47L, 47L, 48L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

